# Is it possible to run terminal commands from actionscript?

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, screenshot

I am currently working on a small as3 application for mac to take screenshots of selected portion of screen. So i wanted to know if it is possible to run the terminal code from the actionscript code.

For example this line of terminal code :

```
screencapture -x -R20,20,640,380 ~/Desktop/test.png
```

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic since that makes it a non-programming question.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) class to send a command to the respective OS's command interpreter application.

> AIR on Windows does not allow you to run .bat files directly. Windows .bat files are executed by the command interpreter application (cmd.exe). When you invoke a .bat file, this command application can interpret arguments passed to the command as additional applications to launch.

For macs, launch the Terminal from the Utilities folder.

Reference [this tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html) to get started.